# C++ performance: using declaratives Vs using declarations Vs using names directly from the library

Tags: c++, performance

I use **using declaration**s more than using the explicit `std::` way for using the standard library objects. I got this question of whether is there any performance increase with using **using declaration**s, **using declarative**s and using names directly from the standard library.

For instance:

To print out "Hello world" we can write the following ways:

- By using the bare `std::` way:

  `std::cout << "Hello world";`
- By using *using declaration*:

  `using std::cout; cout << "Hello world";`
- By using *using declarative*:

  `using namespace std; cout << "Hello world";`

So, **Which of the above methods has the best perfomance? and more efficient?**

Comment: I don't believe they have any effect at runtime.  They're mostly about the effort required to type your source code.

Comment: Why do you suspect there is a difference in performance?

Comment: Because I felt that if all the various names are added by using the using declarative then the compile time would increase a bit.

Comment: And in addition I also felt that by calling the names directly from the standard library would give a performance increase.

Comment: When in doubt, check the assembly language listing **and profile**.

Comment: It's unclear why you think your feelings have any impact on this code. Trust the data, not your feelings. Test, don't assume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All three methods will result in the same runtime code, and thus performance. (easily verified by switching to assembly output, e.g. `g++ -O3 -S test.cpp`).

Should you be talking about compile time, it is very unlikely that this would have any measurable impact. Theoretically fully qualifying the name (`::std::cout`) could reduce the number of potential symbols that need to be checked. However, disk I/O will in all likelihood be far more significant. In fact, I ran a test compiling a simple program 100 times in three variants: `::std::cout`, `std::cout` and `using namespace std; cout`. Even when compiling without optimizations (to make symbol lookup as significant as possible) and on a fast SSD (to minimize disk I/O times) any difference was below the noise level.

Comment: If you are on a system where `std::cout` is not the same as `::std::cout` - Run away!

Comment: @BoPersson absolutely

Answer (score 2):

This has no effect on run-time performance.  using is applied at compile time

Answer (score 0):

These methods are fully the same to compare in run-time, because `using` is previously compiled.

But if you want to create your own namespace you should be careful.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace test
{
   int a = 1;
}

using namespace test;

int main()
{
   int a = 3;
   std::cout << test::a << std::endl; // prints 1
   std::cout << a << std::endl; // be careful, prints 3
   return 0;
}
```

When you are using the method above you make your namespace global. It means that when you declare another variable `a` in the `main()` function, it will hide the variable `a` from `test`. You can still have the access to this variable by typing `test::a`, but `a` without `test::` will refer to the local variable.

To avoid it, don't use `using namespace your_namespace` if you don't need it. It's better to write one more word to make your code safe.

If you are using some variables from namespace very often you could declare it in this way `using your_namespace::variable`.